# Package Manager Console stopped working in Visual Studo

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Yesterday Package Management Console was working fine.
Today when I open it I receive the error

File C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\NUGET\Modules\NuGet\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

I went to the Microsoft link but I have not changed anything with Powershell.
What happened and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio seemed to fix it.